# Calculating sample size in R

Tags: r, sample-size, sample

I'm trying to calculate sample size and I have a Cohen F of .25, and I want to use power of .8. Is there a function in R that will let me calculate sample size based on these values?

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function pwr.anova.test () in the pwr package.